# Recessed LED lighting orange connectors

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, led, recessed-lighting

Installing 12 recessed light cans in the basement. Figured I'd go LED, so I purchased a dozen HALO LED housings (H750T). Then I spotted a deal on Philips LED lights and ordered a dozen from HD online. Both have these little orange connectors, so I just figured they were compatible.

Well, the got the lights today and they are not. What are my options here? Is there something else I need to buy, or can I cut these off and connect with wirenuts?

[image]

Comment: I'd snip off the screw-in edison bases that they gave you in the kit, snip off the connectors in your cans, wire-nut the remaining wires from the bases into those wires, then use the connectors on those cables to plug in the lights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I searched far and wide to find a solution for this for my own remodel.  The orange connectors used by most of the lighting manufacturers is a standard IDEAL product - you can order them online in large quantity or on auction sites in smaller ones.  You can retrofit the HALO cans to be compatible, or even use the connectors (as I did) to connect to GU10 sockets to enable use of LED spots with LED cans.  The IDEAL model is [Ideal 182 30-682](http://www.idealind.com/prodDetail.do?prodId=powerplug_2wire_retrofit).

Then you can just quick connect to your wires, plug together and you're good to go.  Surprised these are so hard to find given how prevalent they are in the LED cans and retrofit bulbs.

Answer (score 1):

If you got the halos at big box just go back and ask them to find compatible connectors and snip your LED connectors off.  I would do it this way so that you can reuse for other light kits.

Note: The connectors are proprietary HALO.  I suggest contacting them and saying that you have messed a few up from their light kit and recessed housing.  The might send you a link to buy them - if they sell them.  These connectors are only rated to 20W and basically keep you from plugging in incandescent.   It is really sad that a big name like HALO is trapping you into their trims (or making a lot of work).

Comment: Thanks, I agree. I wish I had just bought the incandescent housings. The modules they sell with these are really expensive.

Comment: Id return the Halo housings.  Give you more options in the future for connecting up other trims/lights. They are only like $8 for the IC. I just use the included edison adapter and call it good. That way when I can afford more of the Philips Hue Lights I'm al set to screw them in.

Answer (score 0):

Actually those connectors just pop off with a small pick.  You can convert the can to the light or the light to the can.

Not rocket science